# In Tensorflow.js, in Web Browser (windows) , how to save and load model to/from PC disk

Tags: tensorflow.js

I use Tensorflow.js to train model on pictures.
Then I want to save model on my pc-disk, and then reload it.

```
// create new model
_net = await mobilenet.load();
...
// training...
const activation = _net.infer( img, true);
_classifier.addExample( activation, classId);
...
//save on disk
_net.model.save( on_pc_disk);
...
// load from disk
_net.model = ...
```

How to do that ?

Comment: similar scenario: <https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6749#issuecomment-1216940529>

Comment: Ok. I will switch to nodejs application instead WebBrowser.